# Why are my buttons not animating?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So I have a simple web page with 6 buttons. Each button has it's own ID. I have some JQuery code that I learned from Codecademy and tried to translate it to my file. My question is, why is it not animating my buttons the same way it did in the Codecademy editor? It's supposed to increase the height of my button but it isn't. Here's my code.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US">
<meta charset="UTF-8" content="Legacy Gamers">
 <head>
  <title>Legacy Gamers</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="C:\Users\Liam\Desktop\styles.css" media="screen" />
 </head>
 <body id="body1">
  <script type="text/javascript" src="C:\Users\Liam\Desktop\script.js"></script>
  <div><img src="http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5.gif" alt="Legacy Gamers"></div>
  <div id="parentbox">
   <div id="centerwrapper">
    <div class="boxdiv"><button id="box1" class="boxes">Help Me</button></div>
    <div class="boxdiv"><button id="box2" class="boxes">Help Me</button></div>
    <div class="boxdiv"><button id="box3" class="boxes">Help Me</button></div>
    <div class="boxdiv"><button id="box4" class="boxes">Help Me</button></div>
    <div class="boxdiv"><button id="box5" class="boxes">Help Me</button></div>
    <div class="boxdiv"><button id="box6" class="boxes">Help Me</button></div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

```css
#body1 {
 background-image: url("https://i.ytimg.com/vi/XQaNEEotaSw/maxresdefault.jpg");
}

img {
 margin: auto;
 position: absolute;
 padding-top: 100px;
 top: 10;
 left: 0;
 bottom: 1;
 right: 0;
}

.boxes {
    display: inline-block;
 border: none;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
 font-size: 16px;
 opacity: 0.8;
    filter: alpha(opacity=40);
}

.boxdiv {
 float: left;
    margin:1pt;
    width:72pt;
    height:72pt;
 padding-left: 30px;
 padding-bottom: 30px;
}

#parentbox {
 margin: auto;
 position: absolute;
 padding-top: 400px;
 top: 10;
 left: 0;
 bottom: 1;
 right: 0;
}

#centerwrapper {
 margin: auto;
    width: 302pt;
}

#box1 {
 height:100px;
    width:100px;
 background-color: #4dff4d; /* Green */
}

#box2 {
 height:100px;
    width:100px;
 background-color: #ff4d4d; /* Red */
}

#box3 {
 height:100px;
    width:100px;
 background-color: #4d4dff; /* Blue */
}

#box4 {
 height:100px;
    width:100px;
 background-color: #db4dff; /* Purple */
}

#box5 {
 height:100px;
    width:100px;
 background-color: #4dffff; /* Light Blue */
}

#box6 {
 height:100px;
    width:100px;
 background-color: #ff4da6; /* Pink */
}
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
   $("box1").mouseenter(function() {
       $(this).animate({
           height: '+=10px'
       });
   });
   $("#box1").mouseleave(function() {
       $(this).animate({
           height: '-=10px'
       }); 
   });
   $("#box1").click(function() {
       $(this).toggle(1000);
   }); 
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you import the JQuery library?

For example, put this into the head

`<script type = "text/javascript"src = "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>`

Comment: How would I go about doing that? I am still very new to all of this.

Comment: I just edited it. Add that code to the head. The only thing that might go wrong is the version might not be correct for your browser. That would require changing the numbers, but just see first.

Comment: With what you have there though, how would it read my .js file? The src doesn't link to my specific file. Am I supposed to make another script tag? I did that and still nothing is animating.

Comment: Nevermind. I just had to change a few things. Thanks! EDIT: For future people using this thread to answer any questions, `<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>` is the newer version. Always check here [link](https://developers.google.com/speed/libraries/#jquery) for the newest version.